# web api 2 owin bearer token JwtFormat , how to return the same token for several logins (OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and external)

Tags: asp.net, owin, jwt, webapi2

I have an authentication server that return a token for several platforms (mobile,web etc),
then with this token they can do requests to my API .
Something like this : http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

Now i need to add external login (facebook ,google,twitter).

I implemented it like in this guide :
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services

What that i don't understand is how can i return the same token like i return in the regular authentication (for be able to request the API later) .

My api know only the custom jwt token .

Do i need to do it manually from GetExternalLogin function  ?

If yes so i did something like this :

**var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props); 
var accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);**

And now i need to know 
1)need to add to properties IssuedUtc ,ExpiresUtc , how ? in the regular authentication is automatic filled 
2)How to return it to client ?

I saw that in account controller in the end i need to do :
Authentication.SignIn(identity);

And in provider : 
context.Validated(ticket);

maybe i can do the same in account controller ?

Thanks.